# Explain why it is impossible to construct a matrix with these column space and nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Column space has basis
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        1 \\
        3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
Nullspace has basis
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        3 \\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\tag{2}\label{2}
$$

Because both column space and nullspace's basis only have $1$ vector, so they are one dimensional. From (\ref{1}), I know the rank of this matrix is $r = 1$. And from (\ref{2}), $n - r = 1$. So I can get $n = 2$. But the solution says $r + (n - r)$ must be $3$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Both the domain and codomain are 3-dimensional, so the dimensions of the matrix must be ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nullspace of a $m\times n$ matrix is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. So in this case $n=3$. But as you showed, $n=2$. So there cannot be such matrix.

Comment: Why $n = 3$? I remember $n$ stands for the number of columns in the matrix, but I don't know how many columns are there. Do you mean $n$ can be inferred from the nullspace? Because nullspace is 3D, so $n = 3$? Doesn't that means the number of rows is 3, that is $m = 3$?

Comment: You cannot multiply a $m\times n$ matrix with a $3\times 1$ matrix (an element of your nullspace) unless $n=3$ (remember the definition of matrix multiplication). So $n$ can be inferred from the number of components of the vectors in nullspace, not the dimension of nullspace and we know that the number of components of vectors in nullspace is $3$.